# Azure DevOps - Work item types dissapearing from Sprint Taskboard

Tags: azure-devops

I created a new process starting from Basic and created 4 work items: Task, Bug, Support and Change Request.

When I create a task under a Change Request, then the Change Request disappears from the Sprint Taskboard. Is there a way to show both Change Requests and subsequent tasks in the Sprint Taskboard?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can customize the backlogs as you need. You can add the work item type to the backlog level you need.  See [Customize your backlogs or boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process-backlogs-boards?view=azure-devops) for more details.

Example:

When adding the Change Request to requirement backlog, it will be the same level as Issue.

[image]

When adding the Change Request to Iteration backlog, it will be the same level as Task.

[image]